# combine two datasets with different dimension by ID

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two datasets:

```
df1:
    ID score
1   1    30
2   1    10
3   1    22
4   2    44
5   2     6
6   3     5
7   3    20
8   4    35
9   4     2
10  4    60
11  5    14
12  5     5

df2:
    ID para1 para2
1   1    10     5
2   1    10     5
3   2    20    10
4   2    20    10
5   3    30    15
6   4    40    20
7   4    40    20
8   4    40    20
9   4    40    20
10  5    50    25
11  5    50    25
12  5    50    25
13  6    60    30
14  6    60    30
```

I would like to combine df1 and df2 by ID and get df3 below. Tried merge and left_join but they don't work well as I probably missed something. Any simple way to get this?

```
df3:
    ID score para1 para2
1   1    30    10     5
2   1    10    10     5
3   1    22    10     5
4   2    44    20    10
5   2     6    20    10
6   3     5    30    15
7   3    20    30    15
8   4    35    40    20
9   4     2    40    20
10  4    60    40    20
11  5    14    50    25
12  5     5    50    25
```

Comment: try `full_join`

Comment: When merging, you have to be thoughtful about how to handle duplicated rows. Either drop duplicates (as Stefan suggested), add an index to differentiate them, or do a `full_join()` and have duplicates in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to first get rid of the duplicated rows in your `df2` using e.g. `dplyr::distinct`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(distinct(df2, ID, para1, para2))
#> Joining, by = "ID"
#>    ID score para1 para2
#> 1   1    30    10     5
#> 2   1    10    10     5
#> 3   1    22    10     5
#> 4   2    44    20    10
#> 5   2     6    20    10
#> 6   3     5    30    15
#> 7   3    20    30    15
#> 8   4    35    40    20
#> 9   4     2    40    20
#> 10  4    60    40    20
#> 11  5    14    50    25
#> 12  5     5    50    25
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(
  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
  5L, 5L
), score = c(
  30L, 10L, 22L, 44L, 6L, 5L, 20L, 35L, 2L,
  60L, 14L, 5L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1", "2",
  "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"
))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(
  1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L,
  5L, 5L, 6L, 6L
), para1 = c(
  10L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 40L,
  40L, 40L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 60L, 60L
), para2 = c(
  5L, 5L, 10L, 10L,
  15L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 30L, 30L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1",
  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13",
  "14"
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `data.table` would be to do a join and keep the first matched row in the second data.frame.

In this case, take the subset of `df2`, where that key column's values match `df1`'s key column's values based on `ID` key.

You can also include a `nomatch` argument to fill in a value if there's no match. See `?data.table` for more details.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df2[df1, mult = "first", on = "ID"]
```

**Output**

```
    ID para1 para2 score
 1:  1    10     5    30
 2:  1    10     5    10
 3:  1    10     5    22
 4:  2    20    10    44
 5:  2    20    10     6
 6:  3    30    15     5
 7:  3    30    15    20
 8:  4    40    20    35
 9:  4    40    20     2
10:  4    40    20    60
11:  5    50    25    14
12:  5    50    25     5
```